# Use AJAX Search Lite Plugin in Top Navigation in Header file - WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to use the this "AJAX Search Lite 3.0.6" in WordPress Theme.

[`Plugin Link`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/)

When i use this the shortcode it didn't appear on the navigation bar:

```
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <section>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                 <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite'); ?>
           ....
```

How can i make it work? Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: missing `]` in your shortcode update as below `<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]'); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your shortcode

**instead of**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite'); ?>
```

**change this**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]'); ?>
```

Thanks,